# Understanding Two's Complement Addition

Tags: binary, addition, twos-complement

I've built a four bit adder/subtractor utilizing 4, 1 bit full adders and the input and output are twos complement numbers.

If `X=0111 and Y=1000` their sum is obviously 1111.

In decimal this is equivalent to 7 + 8 thus 15 which is what the sum results in.

I am confused however if this result needs to be translated back into "regular" binary by flipping the bits and adding one? So that the answer would be 0001 representing 1 in decimal instead. And that Y in decimal before translation was actually 0110 representing 6 thereby yielding the following in binary `7-6 = 1`. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you've got the conversion for Y wrong. Y = 1000<sub>2</sub> = -8<sub>10</sub>.

To represent -6 you take 0110, flip the bits to get 1001 and add one, so Y = 1010. (And 0111 + 1010 = 0001 as you expect.)

To go back, flip the bits of 1010 = 0101 and add one giving 0110 = 6.

Edit to answer your follow-up question:

Let:

```
X = 0111
Y = 1100

X + Y = 0011 (ignoring overflow)
```

So whatever we're adding, it equals 3. We know that X = 7.

```
Y = 1100 => 0011 + 1 = (negative)0100 = -4
```

7 + (-4) = 3

No translation is necessary, just represent the positive and negative numbers correctly. I think your confusion is coming from the fact that we're "negating" the negative numbers to find the absolute value of that number and sticking a negative sign in front of it, as in the conversion of Y above. That's because negative numbers in 2's complement aren't as readable as positive numbers, but 0100 is still +4 and 1100 is still -4.

Comment: I'm still confused. Perhaps this will make it clearer. Looking at given x=0111 and y=1000, with a sum of 1111, what would the result, 1111 translate to in decimal, and what would y originally have been in decimal?

Comment: 7 - 8 = -1: take 1111, flip the bits to 0000 and add one to get (negative) 0001.

Comment: And just to be complete, 1000 is 0111+1 = (negative)1000 or -8.

Comment: ah thanks so much! Perhaps you'd be willing to help me with one more? If I keep the x value at 0111 but change y to 1100, the sum is 0011. As I follow your above procedure I see that y, 1100 should be 0100, or 4. So the operation should be 7-4 = 3 (in decimal). 3 is represented by 0011 which is what the result comes to without moving the result through the 2's complement procedure described. Do I only need to translate if the leading digit is equal to 1? Or am I still not getting something?

Comment: So I guess the short answer to this last question is yes, only numbers with the high (sign) bit set are negative. Though you have to be careful about when you can and cannot ignore overflow.